# How to initialize an array of semaphore and use it?

Tags: c, semaphore

I would like to create an array of 5 semaphore such that only the first semaphore value has a value of 1 {1,0,0,0,0}. However, when I run the code, it gives me segfault. Am i initializing it correctly and using it correctly? Basically since the first semaphore has a value of 1 the first child will not be blocked, after the first child executing successfully, it will signal the second child to execute , etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_PROCESSES 5

int main()
{

    int i, j, pid;
    int shmid;
    sem_t *sem[5];

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) * 5 , IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    *sem = (sem_t *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    sem_init(sem[0], 1, 1);

    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_PROCESSES; k++)
    {
        sem_init(sem[k], 1, 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        sem_wait(sem[i]);
        printf("I am child %d\n", i);

        for (j = i * 10; j < i * 10 + 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            usleep(250000);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
        sem_post(sem[i + 1]);
        shm_destroy(sem[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
    }
}
```

Second edit: Using sem without pointer, now my issue becomes after printing the first child, the program hangs (non terminate and not printing anything).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_PROCESSES 5

int main()
{

    int i, j, pid;
    int shmid;
    sem_t sem[5];

    sem_init(&sem[0], 1, 1);

    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_PROCESSES; k++)
    {
        sem_init(&sem[k], 1, 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem[i]);

        printf("I am child %d\n", i);

        for (j = i * 10; j < i * 10 + 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            usleep(250000);
        }

        printf("\n\n");

        if (i + 1 < NUM_PROCESSES)
        {
            sem_post(&sem[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Third version: Using a shared memory region but run into segfault again. I do not understand what is going on now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_PROCESSES 5

int main()
{

    int i, j, pid;
    int shmid;
    sem_t *sem[NUM_PROCESSES];

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) * NUM_PROCESSES, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    *sem = (sem_t *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    sem_init(sem[0], 1, 1);

    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_PROCESSES; k++)
    {
        sem_init(sem[k], 1, 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (sem_post(sem[i + 1]) != -1)
        {
            printf("hello");
        }
        sem_wait(sem[i]);

        printf("I am child %d\n", i);

        for (j = i * 10; j < i * 10 + 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", j);

            fflush(stdout);
            usleep(250000);
        }

        printf("\n\n");

        if (i + 1 < NUM_PROCESSES)
        {
            sem_post(sem[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing indeterminate pointer values to `sem_init`. Thereafter, undefined behavior. What do you surmise those five pointers in `sem` point *to* ?

Comment: I want the sem_init to initialize the sem array to its respective value, the first element being one, the rest being zero

Comment: How can I modify that?

Comment: Don't use an array of `sem_t*` . Use an array of `sem_t`, and initialize and access them using pointer arithmetic offset. All the sem functions require the address of a `sem_t`, so declare your array as `sem_t sem[5];` and access each element address by using *either* `&sem[i]`, or the equivalent expression, `(sem+i)`. Both will return the address of the i'th sem_t in the array, which is what all those sem functions are expecting.

Comment: `sem_post(&sem[i+1]);` is accessing an out-of-bounds element when `i` is `NUM_PROCESSES-1`. (Also, you ought to be using `NUM_PROCESSES` for the length of the array, not a literal `5`.)

Comment: ok edited! but it still does not proceed to a different processes.

Comment: The second version won't work because each child process has its own copy of the array of semaphores. They should be in shared memory like the first version. (I'm not sure why @NateEldredge deleted his answer, but it looked correct.)

Comment: however, wen I used a shared memory version, I got segmentation fault error. How do I resolve that?

Comment: I wonder why you have not used `sem_open`? Just use named semaphore between 2 processes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of `sem_t` on the stack (as in OP's second attempt) is not suitable for inter-process communication because the current state of the semaphores would be copied to the child processes by `fork()` and the child processes would operate on their own copies of the semaphores.  So the array of `sem_t` should be initialized within a shared memory segment (as in OP's first attempt). In the calls to `fork()`, the child process inherits the attached shared memory segment of the parent, so all the child processes will use the same semaphores in that memory segment.

The code in the OP's first attempt is incorrect. It is allocating the correct amount of memory, but is treating the memory as an array
of `sem_t *` instead of an array of `sem_t`. It is assigning a pointer to the shared memory segment to the first element of the array, but is using other elements of the array without initializing them.

Those number `5`s ought to be replaced with the macro `NUM_PROCESSES` for consistency. Also, there is no need to explicitly cast the return value of the `shmat` call to `sem_t *` because conversion of `void *` to another object type does not need an explicit cast.

Old code:

```
    sem_t *sem[5];

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) * 5 , IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    *sem = (sem_t *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    sem_init(sem[0], 1, 1);

    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_PROCESSES; k++)
    {
        sem_init(sem[k], 1, 0);
    }
```

Corrected code:

```
    sem_t *sem;

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) * NUM_PROCESSES, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    sem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    sem_init(&sem[0], 1, 1);

    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_PROCESSES; k++)
    {
        sem_init(&sem[k], 1, 0);
    }
```

The original code in the child that calls `sem_post` on the next semaphore needs to check that there *is* a next semaphore:

Old code:

```
        sem_post(sem[i + 1]);
```

Corrected code:

```
        if (i + 1 < NUM_PROCESSES)
        {
            sem_post(&sem[i + 1]);
        }
```

The original code in the child has a call `shm_destroy(sem[i]);`. That is not a standard POSIX function. I guess OP meant to call `sem_destroy(sem[i]);`. With the previous corrections, that should now be `sem_destroy(&sem[i]);`.

Old code:

```
        shm_destroy(sem[i]);
```

Corrected code:

```
        sem_destroy(&sem[i]);
```

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_PROCESSES 5

int main(void)
{

    int i, j;
    pid_t pid;
    int shmid;
    sem_t *sem;

    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) * NUM_PROCESSES, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    sem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    sem_init(&sem[0], 1, 1);

    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_PROCESSES; k++)
    {
        sem_init(&sem[k], 1, 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem[i]);
        printf("I am child %d\n", i);

        for (j = i * 10; j < i * 10 + 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            usleep(250000);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
        if (i + 1 < NUM_PROCESSES)
        {
            sem_post(&sem[i + 1]);
        }
        sem_destroy(&sem[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
    }
}
```